# Netlogo: How to count the number of turtles with specific color and plot them on the Y axis

Tags: plot, colors, count, netlogo

I want to count the number of turtles with specific color (Red) and plot them on the Y axis (the X axis is ticks). The following is the sample program, and 3D. We thank you for your cooperation.

[3D image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQf93.png)

```
if (variety = 1)
[
 set-current-plot "Color-Time"
 set-current-plot-pen "CT"
]
plotxy ticks (***add it here***)
```

Comment: `count turtles with [color = red]`

Comment: Thank you very much for your support. The syntax runed without error completely.

Comment: @SethTisue Consider posting an answer. I know it's too basic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
plotxy ticks count turtles with [color = red]
```

Or, if you're always plotting every tick (including tick 0), just:

```
plot count turtles with [color = red]
```

Note that if you put the plotting code inside the plot itself, rather than in the Code tab, then you don't need `set-current-plot` and `set-current-plot-pen` at all. The normal way of doing plotting in NetLogo is to put code in plots, then that code is automatically triggered by using `reset-ticks` and `tick` in the Code tab.

Comment: Thank you very much for your support again! Thanks.